# Cassandra C++ driver on MacOS High Sierra: make: no rule to make target

Tags: c++, cassandra, macos-high-sierra, datastax-php-driver

Following [these instructions](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/) to install the DataStax C++ Driver on MacOS High Sierra, as a pre-requisite to installing the DataStax PHP Driver for Cassandra.

Everything runs great until I get to the line "make install" in the "Building and installing the C/C++ driver" section. That's where I get the message: "make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop."

Can someone help me get past this step?

Comment: Are you in the same directory where you ran make? Did the make succeed without errors?

Comment: Yes I was in the same directory, and "make" ran just fine without errors.

Comment: can you paste the commands that you executed? I just run all steps, and everything works just fine

Comment: The commands I entered are straight from those instructions:

    <pre><code>
$ pushd build
~/build ~
$ cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/crmcmullen/build
$ make
$ make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
$
</pre></code>

Comment: ^^ sorry ... that .... did not format as expected.

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED ** a friend helped me stumble across the solution. Two things to remember when installing on MacOS High Sierra:

1.) You need to run the install of cpp-driver (which isn't a step in the DataStax instructions referenced in the question) and then

2.) You have to fully qualify the cmake .. command to point to the OpenSSL install.

Here are the amended instructions that worked for me:

```
   # Datastax C++ driver dependencies
   brew install libuv cmake
   brew install openssl
   brew link --force openssl

   # Install git if you dont have it
   brew install git

   # Retrieve the cpp 
   git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git --depth=1
   mkdir cpp-driver/build
   cd cpp-driver/build

   # Build with qualified path to OpenSSL location
   cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/ -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ..
   make
   make install

   # Install pecl driver
   pecl install cassandra
```

Once that's complete you should be good to go.